# Polyphase merge sort - what is the number of phases

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose that we have to sort some big set of numbers externally. We want to examine 2 cases:

1. 4 tapes: 2 input tapes, 2 output
2. 3 tapes: 2 in, 1 out

Case 1:

[image: 4 tapes]

We start with `k` runs, then we copy those runs to 2 input tapes (on the left on the pic below), each iteration we take two different runs from the input tapes, merge (and sort) them, and in one iteration save them to the first output tape, and in next iteration - to the second one, as shown below. Then we switch output tapes with input ones and repeat the procedure. So if we have, lets say, `n=10^6` elements and `k=1000` runs, then after the first phase run’s size will be `2000`, after the third `4000` and so on. So the total number of phases is `ceil(log_2(n))`.

Case 2:

[image: 3 tapes]

In the best-case complexity, the number of phases is `position of Fibonacci’s number in the Fibonacci’s sequence minus two`, i.e. if our initial number of runs is `k=34` and 34 is the 9th number in the Fibonacci sequence, then we will have 7 phases.

[image]

But… if our number of runs isn’t a Fibonacci number, it is necessary to pad the tape with dummy runs in order to get no. of runs up to Fibonacci number.

Finally, my question is:

What is the average-case number of phases needed in order to sort a sequence, when the number of runs isn’t a Fibonacci number?

Comment: What you’ve described is a balanced merge. Polyphase reads from 1 take and distributes to 3, then starts merging 3 tapes to 1 repeatedly (modulo handwaving).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the number of phases ... when number of runs isn’t a Fibonacci number?

If the run count is not an ideal number, then the sort will take one extra phase, similar to rounding the run count up to the next ideal number. Dummy runs don't need to occupy any space on the tapes, but the code has to handle reaching the end of data on more than one tape during a phase on non-ideal distributions.

---

Some notes about the information in the original question:

The 4 tape example shows a balanced 2-way merge sort. For polyphase merge sort, there's only one output tape per phase. With 4 tape drives, the initial setup distributes runs between the 3 other drives, so after the initial distribution, it is always 3 input tapes, 1 output tape.

The Fibonacci numbers only apply to a 3 tape scenario. For a 4 or more tape scenario, the sequence is easiest to generate by starting at the final phase and working backwards. For 31 runs on 4 tapes, the final run count is {1,0,0,0},
working backwards: {0,1,1,1}, {1,0,2,2}, {3,2,0,4}, {7,6,4,0}, {0,13,11,7}.

The run sizes increase as the result of merging prior runs of various sizes. Assume run size is 1 element, 31 runs, 4 tapes. After initial distribution, run count:run size is {0:0,13:1,11:1,7:1}. First phase: {7:3,6:1,4:1,0:0}. Second phase: {3:3,2:1,0:0,4:5}. Third phase {1:3,0:0,2:9,2:5}. Fourth phase: {0:0,1:17,1:9,1:5}. Fifth and final phase {1:31,0:0,0:0,0:0}.

Keeping track of run sizes can get complex, so a simple solution for tapes is to use a single file mark or smaller than normal record|block to indicate the end of a run and a double or single file mark to indicate the end of data.

Wiki has an article on polyphase merge sort.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphase_merge_sort

---

If the total run count is known in advance, the initial distribution can include initial merge operations to get the run count to an ideal number, but now the run sizes vary due to the initial merge operations, so each tape ends up with a mix of run sizes. Again, using file marks or smaller than normal records | blocks to indicate end of runs eliminates having to keep track of run sizes in memory.

Polyphase merge sort is the fastest way to do a sort using 3 stacks.

Comment: The 4-tapes method described in my question is called **balanced** 2-way merge sort, http://bluehawk.monmouth.edu/rclayton/web-pages/s06-503/esort.html

Comment: @SantaXL - I updated my answer to note this. I wasn't sure if the 4 tape example was supposed to show a balanced merge sort or polyphase merge sort. Polyphase merge sort is faster for less than 8 tapes, while balanced merge sort is faster for 8 or more tapes.

Comment: *Cascade* merge is faster for 8 or more tapes. Balanced merge isn’t faster for any *N.*

Comment: @user207421 - If the tape drives can read and write in parallel, then with 8 tape drives, two 4 tape sorts could be run in parallel (except for final merge), favoring polyphase merge sort. If tape drives support read backwards, that can save rewind time. For cascade, this means alternating direction of merge with each pass. For polyphase, this means alternating direction with each merge, and complicates the initial distribution of runs. Most of the optimized tape sorts were proprietary, and the details of their implementations have been lost.